# How to get PublicKey from PKCS10CertificationRequest using new Bouncy Castle library?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

In the new version of Bouncy Castle library there are changes in `PKCS10CertificationRequest`. In previous versions it was possible to get `PublicKey` from such request using `getPublicKey()` method (see [old doc](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/jce/PKCS10CertificationRequest.html#getPublicKey%28%29)).

Now this method disappered. How can I get PublicKey from with from such request?
There is `getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().parsePublicKey()` but it returns `ASN1Primitive`.

I see that from SPKAC `NetscapeCertRequest` I still can read PublicKey directly by calling `getPublicKey()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a utility class in the main provider package called [PublicKeyFactory](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PublicKeyFactory.html). The method [createKey](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PublicKeyFactory.html#createKey%28org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo%29) returns an [AsymmetricKeyParameter](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AsymmetricKeyParameter.html) which you cast to whatever type of public key is appropriate, e.g.

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo pkInfo = pkcs10CertReq.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
RSAKeyParameters rsa = (RSAKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(pkInfo);
```

EDIT 1:

In addition, to create a `java.security.PublicKey` a few more steps are needed:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec rsaSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsa.getModulus(), rsa.getExponent());
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey rsaPub = kf.generatePublic(rsaSpec);
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to cast it I got: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyParameters cannot be cast to java.security.PublicKey`

Comment: Michal Niklas:  No, of course not, I meant cast it to the appropriate type of Bouncycastle public key. I'll add the code to convert to Java public key in a minute

Comment: @GregS : This relies on the fact that algorithm used in public key is already known, is there any way to determine algorithm used as well?

Comment: @GregS : Thanks there is an Algorithm Identifier, I tried to use it by comparing it to various algorithms. I can find rsaAlgorithm is an ObjectIdentifier but same doesn't go for ECC. Is there any single identifier enum for all algorithms?

Comment: @gaurav: I don't think so, they seem to be distributed over several classes.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking at the same issue, and this will work too (with the advantage that we don't need to specify the algorithm):

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo pkInfo = pkcs10CertReq.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
PublicKey pubKey = converter.getPublicKey(pkInfo);
```

See [org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.3/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMKeyConverter.html)

Answer (score 4):

What about using JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest?

```
JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest(pkcs10CertReq);
PublicKey publicKey = jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Edit your answer with explanation.

Comment: you can also use the bouncyCastle class JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest initializing it with the PKCS10CertificationRequest and then extract the PublicKey using the getPublicKey() method.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
PKCS10CertificationRequest csr =...;    
PublicKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().toASN1Primitive().getEncoded()));
```

[RFC 2986 - PKCS #10: Certification Request Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986)

> CertificationRequestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
> version       INTEGER { v1(0) } (v1,...),
> subject       Name,
> subjectPKInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo{{ PKInfoAlgorithms }},
> attributes    [0] Attributes{{ CRIAttributes }}
> }

> SubjectPublicKeyInfo { ALGORITHM : IOSet} ::= SEQUENCE {
> algorithm        AlgorithmIdentifier {{IOSet}},
> subjectPublicKey BIT STRING
> }

and then, you can see the document of java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

> SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
> algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
> subjectPublicKey BIT STRING }

so you will know the encoding of this public key is X.509. and then change it to X509EncodedKeySpec and generate public key by keyFactory

Comment: the code of James K Polk is convert the key to PKCS#1 encoding

Comment: using JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest  is a good idea ,  the code of amareno